# Issue with RPi and BLDC controller board

Tags: pwm, raspberry-pi, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I'm having some trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong so hopefully someone can spot my error and help set me straight.

These are my motor and the board with everything labeled. Then below that is the schematic of how I have it all hooked up.

I have a PWM output on the BCM 16 pin.  The board adjusts the speed based on the input voltage from 0v-5v.  I've run the program on the RPi and tested the output voltage and PWM works perfectly.

BCM 20 outputs 3.3v "high" to set the direction of the spin.
BCM 21 outputs 3.3v "high" to enable the motor.

The board technically states that the "high" state is 5v so just in case 3.3v wasn't enough I've also connected it straight to a 5v pin.

I tested all the pins and they are all outputting the voltage they should be.  The power source for the motor was tested and is outputting 48v.

Everything looks like it should work but when I run the RPi nothing happens with the motor.

So my biggest question is: does it look like it's wired up correctly?  The main question mark I had was the 5v and ground to the hall sensors on the board. Do the black and red wires from the motor connect there or are there supposed to be from the RPi?

[image: Motor]
[image: Board]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fln5ct.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I am sorry, but what do you expect? The board seems to be quite simple, just try applying analog input without RPi, see what happens.

Comment: What is your question? And, if you think the question might be "why doesn't it work", put yourself in the position of anyone reading this question and think about what they may ask you to clarify. Apart from anything else that stepper motor looks like it's been salvaged from a dump site. Prove that IT works correctly is my advice.

Comment: If you disconnect A/B/C and watch the phases with an oscilloscope while using a handheld electric drill to spin the motor's rotor, you should be able to see sinusoidal back EMF at 120 degree intervals on the motor phases. This would confirm the motor is ok. Connect 5V to the hall effect sensors and check their output, those should look like pulses (if RPM is high enough). Once motor is confirmed good, connect A/B/C to the ESC board without the RPi, and test the ESC using analog control input. Is Enable active-high or active-low?  Without hall-effect sensors ESC should at least try to start.